# filtering through user variables to get the user I need is not working, also creating links from one user to another

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase

So I have this page that displays information about the different types of users I have. On the student's page I am trying to display the parent of each student on that page underneath the parent heading, the way to do that is to compare the parent_email variable in each student to the email variable in each parent and find the one that's the same then display that parent's name as a link to their detailed user page.

So far, just to begin, I've tried doing a nested for loop that compares the two variables and then displays the parent's name or something simple to let me know that the parent has been found but unfortunately every solution I can think of breaks the page on the site instead. This is the code I have (some of the commented code is parts of solutions I have tried). I'm not very familiar with php and html so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

inside the function is not getting inside the if loop that compares emails:
if (users[i][1].parent_email == users[j][1].email)

```
function displayUsers(user_type)
{
    document.getElementById("user-list").style.display = 'block';
    firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('user_type').equalTo(user_type).once("value", function(snapshot)
    {

        if(user_type == "parent" || user_type == "student")
        {
            for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
            {
                //table_rows += "<tr>";

                let name = users[i][1].first_name + " " + users[i][1].last_name;
                let key = users[i][0];

                for(let j = 0; j < users.length; j++)
                {
                    //table_rows += "<tr>";

                    let name1 = users[j][1].first_name + " " + users[i][1].last_name;
                    let key1 = users[j][0];

                    if (users[i][1].parent_email == users[j][1].email)
                    {
                        //table_rows += users[i][1].parent_email;
                        //table_rows += "<tr>";
                        if (user_type == "student")
                        {
                            table_rows += "<tr>";
                            table_rows += `<td id='name1-` + j +`'>
                                                <button class="rounded user-info-btn" type="button">
                                                    <a id='name1-link-${j}' style="color:white" href="detailed_user_info.php?key=${key1}&type=${users[j][1].user_type}">${name1}<a>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>`;
                        }

                        if (user_type == "parent")
                        {
                            table_rows += "<tr>";
                            table_rows += `<td id='name-` + i +`'>
                                    <button class="rounded user-info-btn" type="button">
                                        <a id='name-link-${i}' style="color:white" href="detailed_user_info.php?key=${key}&type=${users[i][1].user_type}">${name}<a>
                                    </button>
                                </td>`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited the code to only contain the things that matter most but I am not sure it makes as much sense without all the context. is there anyway you can take a look and let me know? thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't help. I would recommend using some `console.debug()` statements inside of your code so that you can see what is actually going on and comparing that with what you expect.

Comment: I edited the code again to only include the important part and I tested it, it doesn't seem to be getting into the if loop that compares the emails, if you have any suggestions.